# game countdown bad accuracy in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm developing a game in [react-native](https://reactnative.dev/) and the main game *View* must contain also a countdown. Here I reduce it to just have a numeric representation.
I wrote a simple custom hook `useTimer` mainly to check how much the timing fluctuations make the actual time diverge from the target.

```js
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
const useTimer = (ms, tick) => {
    const [time, setTime] = useState(ms),
        [started, setStarted] = useState(false),
        ref = useRef(),
        stop = () => {ref.current && clearInterval(ref.current)},
        start = time => {
            time && setTime(time)
            setStarted(true)
        };
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!started || time <= 0) { stop() return stop}
        ref.current = setInterval(() => setTime(t => t - tick), tick)
        return stop
    }, [time, started])
    return { time: (time / 1e3).toFixed(2), start, stop }
};

export default useTimer;
```

then in a naked *View*

```js
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, Pressable } from 'react-native'
import useTimer from './../hooks/useTimer'
import {FIFTYTHREE, tick} from './../constants'
/**
 * as u might suspect FIFTYTHREE value is 53
 * then tick is 10, yes 10
 */
const Timer = () => {
    const {start, stop, time} = useTimer(FIFTYTHREE * 1e3, tick)
    return <View>
            <Pressable  onPress={() => start()}>
                <Text>{time}</Text>
            </Pressable>
    </View>
};
export default Timer
```

then I start it in the emulator and everything seems fine for few seconds then,
something feels wrong, it is slow, so I put aside my phone and I measure it roughy takes
**1 minute and 34 seconds**!!!
It is vital for the game that this countdown is quite precise (tolerance ok to ±1%)

It is well know the native `setTimeout` and `setInterval` suffer fluctuations (mostly in excess) which sum up, and this explains the delay, and this grows inversely to the `tick` value;
thus I tried to change `tick` to `100` ms getting the countdown to complete in `59` seconds, quite a good step ahead ...but still far away from the needed constraints.
So just for curiosity I try setting `tick` to `500` ms (really not acceptable to see) and it takes `55` seconds to reach zero.

Next attempt I made was to use a self calibrating version of setInterval I wrote quite some time ago,

```js
var t = 53e3,
    tick = 10,
    start = +new Date,
    end,
    i = interval(() => {
        t -= tick;
        if (t <=0) {
          end = +new Date;
          console.log(end-start)
          i.clear();
        }
    }, tick).run();
```

I got here `53001` in console thus now I can reasonably exclude the interval issue from the equation,
things got better but still the error (excess or defect) is strictly related to the `tick` value and definitely affected the react-native.
Moreover sounds reasonable that also the device specs and resources will concur to distort the measure and making that absolutely non deterministic. This is the reason why I start suspecting there is no way to have a good solution in react-native but I should rather move to ios proper development with swift.

I would like to know if anyone faced and maybe solved a similar problem in react-native or if the only way is really to move to Xcode.

#### UPDATE.

based on [@Viktor W](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9257886/viktor-w) feedback
I updated the hook to

```js
const useTimer = (ms, tick) => {
    const [time, setTime] = useState(ms);
    const ref = useRef();
    useEffect(() => {
        ref.current = interval(() => {
            setTime(t => t - tick)
        }, tick).run()
        return () => ref.current.clear()
    }, [])
    return { time }
};
```

and removed the start button, it starts right away when rendered.
Still it takes 1 min and 28 sec to go to zero :(

Comment: Would the solution be to keep using the tick to trigger the UI update, but have the "time remaining" based on "now - expected end time", where the expected end time would be calculated when first setting up the timer?

Comment: It looks to me like you are creating a new interval in each tick. This is a bad idea, and perhaps the reason for your inefficiency. The reason is that when you call setTime, the component will rerender, and the useEffect retriggered, effectively calling the function stop and then running your effect again. Would it be possible to remove the variable time from the useEffect dependency array?

Comment: @ViktorW absolutely right, I cant actually remove the time dep cause I want to stop it at 0, but there is a easy fix, let me try

Comment: the only option to get acceptably close to 53 is to set the tick to 1000. I'll consider that

Comment: You definitely can't rely on `setInterval` or `setTimeout` to be accurate. Save the starting "wall clock" time (`new Date()`, that is), and compute how much time has passed between the current moment and that start time in your interval tick (which should then be more frequent than 1000 ms).